# SQL- Selecting 1 output for rows with same ID

Tags: sql

I hope there's  enough information below for you to assist

```
Table A
ID Name Location    
A1 John London    
A2 Mike London    
A3 Adam London    
A4 Steve London    
A5 James London


Table B
ID TEST Results    
A1 TEST1 SATISFACTORY    
A1 TEST2 UNSATISFACTORY    
A1 TEST3 SATISFACTORY    
A2 TEST1 SATISFACTORY    
A2 TEST2 UNSATISFACTORY    
A2 TEST3 SATISFACTORY    
A3 TEST1 SATISFACTORY    
A3 TEST2 SATISFACTORY    
A4 TEST1 UNSATISFACTORY    
A4 TEST2 UNSATISFACTORY    
A5 TEST0 NOT TESTED
```

at the moment my query is:

```
Select Distinct TableA.ID, TableA.Name, TableA.Loacation, TableB.ID, 
TableB.Results
Left outer join TableA on TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

So when I run this Query I get the following results

```
ID NAME ID Results
A1 JOHN A1 SATISFACTORY
A1 JOHN A1 UNSATISFACTORY
A2 MIKE A2 SATISFACTORY
A2 MIKE A2 UNSATISFACTORY
A3 ADAM A3 SATISFACTORY
A4 STEVE A4 UNSATISFACTORY
A5 JAMES A5 NOT TESTED
```

---

So if all the tests for a particular ID is SATISFACTORY(A3) then i get 1 output
’A3 ADAM A3 SATISFACTORY’

So if all the tests for a particular ID is UNSATISFACTORY(A4) then i get 1 
 output

```
A4 STEVE A4 UNSATISFACTORY
```

Also if all the tests for a particular ID is NOT TESTED(A5) then i get 1 output

```
A5 STEVE A5 NOT TESTED
```

Though if i have an ID with some SATISFACTORY & UNSATISFACTORY then it returns 2 rows

```
A1 JOHN A1 SATISFACTORY
A1 JOHN A1 UNSATISFACTORY
A2 MIKE A2 SATISFACTORY
A2 MIKE A2 UNSATISFACTORY
```

What i’m trying to achieve is that if there is a mix of SATISFACTORY & UNSATISFACTORY for 1 ID then the output only shows the UNSATISFACTORY. I’ve tried case statement, group by, Joins, MIN/MAX...just having no luck

Comment: Please add a tag to tell us what RDBMS (postgres, oracle,sqlserver etc) this is in

Comment: what you are expecting post the output

Comment: `Select TableA.ID, TableA.Name, TableA.Location,
MAX(TableB.Results)
Left outer join TableA on TableA.ID = TableB.ID GROUP BY TableA.ID, TableA.Name, TableA.Location,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, split the problem into 3 cases and union the individual results together:

```
-- SATISFACTORY & UNSATISFACTORY 
SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, 
A.Name, 
B.ID, 
'SATISFACTORY & UNSATISFACTORY' AS Result
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.Results='SATISFACTORY'
AND B.Results='UNSATISFACTORY'
UNION
--SATISFACTORY & NOT UNSATISFACTORY 
SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, 
A.Name, 
B.ID, 
B.Results
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.Results='SATISFACTORY'
AND B.Results<>'UNSATISFACTORY'
UNION
--NOT SATISFACTORY & UNSATISFACTORY 
SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, 
A.Name, 
B.ID, 
B.Results
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B on A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.Results<>'SATISFACTORY'
AND B.Results='UNSATISFACTORY'
```

Comment: Your WHERE logic is weird. Why bother specifying that a column must be simultaneously equal to one value and not equal to another value - logically the not-equal is redundant in the presence of the equals. `WHERE mycol = 1 and mycol != 2` is the same as `WHERE mycol = 1`- think about it

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you haven't elaborated on is the precedence of results. This answer assumes NOT TESTED trumps UNSATISFACTORY trumps SATISFACTORY:

```
SELECT
  table_a.id, table_a.name, b_ranked.test, b_ranked.results
FROM
  table_a
  LEFT JOIN
  (
   SELECT
    id, 
    test,
    results,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, test, ORDER BY CASE results WHEN 'NOT TESTED' THEN 0 WHEN 'UNSATISFACTORY' THEN 1 WHEN'SATISFACTORY' THEN 2) as rown
   FROM 
    table_b
  ) b_ranked
  ON table_a.id = b_ranked.id and b_ranked.rown = 1
```

The magic is done by the row_number() call, it essentially puts an incrementing counter on rows that have the same `id`, `test` and orders the result specifically so the most interesting one for you is always numbered `1`. Most modern databases support this, but yours may not (hence why I asked in the comments). Using this method avoid expensive operations joining the table back onto itself, unions, distincts and other intensive ways of de-duping results

If you want to dig in to see how it works, just run the inner subquery and then work out how it links to the outer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for each `ID`-`Name` pair you intend to get a single record, which will be `UNSATISFIED` if there was at least an `UNSATISFIED` result for the given `ID` and `Name`, `SATISFIED` if there was no `UNSATISFIED`, but was at least a `SATISFIED` and `NOT TESTED` if there was at least a `NOT TESTED` value. Note, that this solution does not include a row in the case where there is no record in `B` for a record in `A`. If you want to include that, you will need to use a `left join` and default `Results` to `NOT TESTED`. The idea used here is based on the observation that

**'NOT TESTED' < 'SATISFIED' < 'UNSATISFIED'**

in your potential result, so if there is at least an `UNSATISFIED`, then it will be the maximum. `SATISFIED` can only be a maximum if `UNSATISFIED` does not exist for the given tester and at least a `SATISFIED` result occurred. Otherwise, if there is a `NOT TESTED` value, then it will be the maximum.

```
select A.ID, A.Name, max(B.Results) as Results
from A
join B
on A.ID = B.ID
group by A.ID, A.Name
```